# Hamiltonian in 2-dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, linear-algebra

I am trying to construct a Hamiltonian for a system in 2 dimensions using Matlab.
I am not sure how this Hamiltonian will look like in matrix form.
If somebody can help me visualize this matrix that will be great.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Your question seems to lack information. Hamiltonion of a specific system?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about a hamiltonian for a two-dimensional quantum system, any self-adjoint (aka hermitian) $2\times2$ matrix with complex entries will do.  Any such matrix must equal its adjoint (conjugate-transpose), and this restricts the matrix to have the following form:
$$
  H = \begin{pmatrix}
  a & c+id\\
c-id & b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers.